# Angular: Injecting router in constructor giving error

Tags: angular, inject

I am trying to create a global error handling component and for this, I am providing custom ErrorHandler class. I want to inject Router through the constructor in error.service.ts so that I can navigate to the error component but it fails with below error.

> compiler.js:18429 Uncaught Error: Provider parse errors:
>   Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1

Here is the link of project. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q56xm8

Please check error.service.ts, it works if I uncomment the first implementation but I want to make it work using below approach.

Comment: You can't use the second approach, due to the problem written in the error message: there would be a circular dependency: the router needs, directly or indirectly, the error handle, and the error handler needs the router. Just use the first way: it's a proper way of dealing with the problem.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it a little as how it works if I inject in component constructor but doesn't work in service.

Comment: Well, you can inject the router in the component, because the router doesn't have your component in its dependencies. So that doesn't create a circular dependency. But the router needs the error handler. So if the error handler also needs the router, that creates a circular dependency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try to understand this by an example of what's happening inside when you registered your custom error handler.

To register the error handler, you did something like:

```
class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  handleError(error) {
    // do something with the exception
  }
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler}]
})
class MyModule {}
```

Now what this did is, it now used your `MyErrorHAndler` class instead of Angular's [**`ErrorHandler`**](https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler).

So let's say in case of the Router, it needs an instance of the `MyErrorHandler` service, to create it's own instance. So the injector is going to look for an instance of `MyErrorHandler` to create an instance of `Router`.

The Injector doesn't have an instance of the `MyErrorHandler` service(instead of the regular `ErrorHandler`) so it will try to create one so that it can provide it to the `Router`. But as soon as it tries to create an instance of `MyErrorHandler` it sees that in the constructor of `MyErrorHandler`, there's `Router`. So it will check for an instance of `Router` that it might inject in the `constructor` of `MyErrorHandler`. But it doesn't find one as `Router` was something it was trying to instantiate in the first place.

**TL;DR;:** Angular in order to create an instance of `Router` needs an instance of `MyErrorHandler`. And in order to create an instance of `MyErrorHandler`, it needs an instance of `Router`. This creates a situation where `MyErrorHandler` depends on `Router` and `Router` depends on `MyErrorHandler` thereby creating a circular dependency.

**Fix:** As you've done it on your own, the fix is to use `Injector`. When you use that, in order to create an instance of `MyErrorHandler` Angular will no longer have to inject an instance of `Router` in it. Hence there won't be a case of any circular dependency in this case.

Comment: how the instantiation would have happend had it been a normal provider like  @NgModule({
  providers: [ MyErrorHandler]
})

Comment: Well, it would have happened normally. Angular's Injector would have been asked to create an instance of MyErrorHandler, it would have checked if it already has one. If not, it would have checked for all the things that the `MyErrorHandler` need to get instantiated, it would have provided them to the constructor of `MyErrorHandler` and would have eventually created an instance of `MyErrorHandler`.